# how do i use loop with double input. first asks for a letter then the output then asks if u wanna play again or quit(1, 2)

Tags: python

so basically I want to start with the door input then check if the door has money or not then ask the user again if he would like to play again using the play input. if user enters 2 then asks again which door and so on. if the user enters 2 or if the number of miss on the door(no money) is = 3 then the game stops. right now the problem is it will run the loop jackpot ==1 till the it hits jackpot == 0 and play ==1 is not working

```
import random
total = 0
miss = 0
prizeMoney = 0
door = input("Enter a character from A to Z representing the door you wish to open:")
while miss < 3:
    if len(door) > 0:
        jackpot = random.randint(0, 1)
        if jackpot == 1:
            prizeMoney = random.randint(500, 1000)
            total = total + prizeMoney
            print("Behind Door", door, " is", prizeMoney, "$")
        elif jackpot == 0 :
            print("Sorry, there is no hidden money behind Door", door, ".This is a miss.")
            miss = miss + 1
            print()
            play = input("Do you wish to quit (1) or open another door (2)?")
            if play == "2" and miss <= 3 :
                door = input("Enter a character from A to Z representing the door you wish to open:")
            else:
                play == "1"
                print("Congratulations!! You have won $", total, ".")
        else:
            miss == "3"
            print("Sorry the game is over. You win $", total, ". Try again.")
    else:
        print("try again")
```

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.
Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.
"is not working" is not a problem specificaiton.

Comment: Your posted code hangs waiting for input -- don't expect us to enter test data, or to build a test file.
Instead, simply hard-code a test case that causes the problem.  Edit your description attempt, for grammar and clarity; use that to make the test case.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code see if this works, there were lots of mistakes I added break statements and refined the logic

```
import random
total = 0
miss = 0
prizeMoney = 0
door = input("Enter a character from A to Z representing the door you wish to open:")
while miss < 3:
    if len(door) > 0:
        jackpot = random.randint(0, 1)
        if jackpot == 1:
            prizeMoney = random.randint(500, 1000)
            total = total + prizeMoney
            print("Behind Door", door, " is", prizeMoney, "$")
            
            play = int(input("Do you wish to quit (1) or open another door (2)?"))
            if play == 2 and miss < 3 :
                door = input("Enter a character from A to Z representing the door you wish to open:")
            else:
                print('only 3 miss allowed or you pressed quit')
                print("Congratulations!! You have won $", total, ".")
                break
            
        elif jackpot == 0 :
            print("Sorry, there is no hidden money behind Door", door, ".This is a miss.")
            miss = miss + 1
            play = int(input("Do you wish to quit (1) or open another door (2)?"))
            if play == 2 and miss < 3 :
                door = input("Enter a character from A to Z representing the door you wish to open:")
            else:
                print('only 3 miss allowed or you pressed quit')
                print("Congratulations!! You have won $", total, ".")
                break 

    else:
        print("try again")
        break
```